# GeoNode, GeoServer for production

Tags: geoserver, geonode, nginx

I have installed following the advanced installation. now I want to publish to the public, but using the (https://docs.geonode.org/en/master/install/advanced/core/index.html#update-the-settings-in-order-to-update-geonode-and-geoserver-services-running-on-a-public-ip-or-hostname) instruction I was able to change the domain for GeoNode, while GeoServer still using the localhost:8080. What is the problem? When the web page is open with localhost:8080/geoserver and I press login, the link changes to public address and it does not login

Comment: can you try using a clean browser? (ie: Clear cookies/private browsing etc etc).

Comment: Did you set the geoserver proxy URL?